# 3D Modeling, Vertex Resolution

Tags: 3d-modeling, sketchup

I'm looking for the following functionality out of a free, or cheap software. I'm very close using google sketchup but I appear to have hit a snag that nobody on their forums can figure out, so I come here.

I want to be able to make a simple 3D model (so far I've just been using the 3D text tool in google sketchup). It will pretty much be limited to common geometric shapes. Cubes, spheres, and various rectangles connected to make letters etc.

Here's the hard part: I need the software to be able to convert the 3D model to a list of xyz coordinates. For example, if I drew a cube at the origin with length 1, I need a way to generate the following list:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
0,1,1
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,1,0
1,1,1
```

Those are the 8 vertices of the cube.

Now let's pretend I used the 3D text tool in google sketch up to make 3D text that says JHU ECE. Not so easy anymore...

Anybody know of software that can do this on the cheap? Actually give me any software you know that can do this because my school has some CAD licenses, but I'm not sure which ones.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the open source [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)?  It has a comprehensive feature set and may do what you need.  There are also plenty of tutorials, which is good because the user interface is rather daunting.